# How to update a certain value in my database based on the value of another child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here's an image of my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/prxs9.jpg

I want to update the child `JtFpeu4kH7YApizjlq6KO4kfKjF2` under users and add the event_id `-L0rlisR_ExF1lMGUTeV`. Here, `JtFpeu4kH7YApizjlq6KO4kfKjF2` is the user-id generated when the user registers in my app with Firebase. This is not a 'push' ID. I am searching based on email. So, the pseudo code would be:

Find out if there is a node with `email = 'dummy@gmail.com'`.

If so, then set `event_id = "-L0rlisR_ExF1lMGUTeV"` in that node.

If not, then put it in a new child called 'unclaimed'(This is working)

But with my approach, the event_id gets set to a node outside of the userId with child name as `Registered` if a match is found. How do I resolve this?

```
final DatabaseReference RegUserCheck = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Registered");
                RegUserCheck.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {

                          /*This adds to a child called 'unclaimed' since the 
                           email doesn't exist. This is working correctly*/

                            DatabaseReference Unclaimed = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Unclaimed").push();
                            Unclaimed.child("Email").setValue(email);
                            Unclaimed.child("Events").setValue(event_key);
                        }

                        else
                        {


/*    THE FOLLOWING LINE JUST TAKES 'REGISTERED' AS THE KEY */
                            RegUserCheck.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("Events").setValue(event_key);



                        }
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Events` inside one `Registered` then instead of this:

```
RegUserCheck.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("Events").setValue(event_key);
```

do this:

```
RegUserCheck.child("Events").setValue(event_key);
```

This way you will have:

```
Registered
     email: email@gmail.com
     User_id: id_here
     Events: -event_key
```

The reason you got an extra `Registered` its because this `child(dataSnapshot.getKey())` adds a child with the key of the dataSnapshot, and dataSnapshot here is equal to `Registered` therefore you got another child called `Registered`.